# Add menu to wordpress page on the editor

Tags: php, html, wordpress, menu, load

I need to add a menu on a wordpress page but on the tinymce editor. I know there are a couple of tags ["example"=something] for plugins so I would like to know if there's anything similar to load a menu.

this is how I'm loading the menu on the editor (php)

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>
```

and what I need is to load the menu between content that is editable for a specific page.

Comment: your question doesn't really make sense! no shortcodes are available for menu load unless you create them. If you want a custom menu per page, you can set a template that calls the spec menu (using `wp_nav_menu( $args )`) look it up you can call diff menus

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your exact requirement. If you need a button on your editor you can use the below code to your themes `functions.php`. This code will add a button tag creator to the editor. Similarly you can add anything in the editor.

```
<?php

// Add buttons to html editor
add_action('admin_print_footer_scripts','eg_quicktags');
function eg_quicktags() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
button = edButtons.length;
edButtons[edButtons.length] = new edButton('ed_paragraph','button','<button>','</button>','button');
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery("#ed_toolbar").append('<input type="button" value="p" id="ed_paragraph" class="ed_button" onclick="edInsertTag(edCanvas, button);" title="p" />');
}); 
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, as the other answer suggests, you're likely going about this the wrong way.  BUT : to solve your problem, wordpress provides a custom menu widget, and there is a plugin to put any widget you like on any page vai the editor, using a shortcode.

Have a look at this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-shortcode/